# GnuCash: Copy & Paste Balance Sheet

Tags: gnucash

I would like to use GnuCash for the limited purpose of inputting an existing balance sheet at a particular point in time (just the totals at year end, NOT any of the activity) in order to enter adjusting journal entries. Is there a quick way to do this without going through the lengthy process of creating individual accounts one by one? This is not to keep the books, just for a demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

You can import a list of new accounts in CSV format, choosing File, Import, Import Accounts from CSV.

In order to establish initial balances for the accounts, you'll need to import initial balance transactions. Create an account for the balances to come from (like "Equity:Opening Balances") if you haven't already, then use the File, Import, Import Transactions from CSV menu option to import a file into the Opening Balances account that transfers the balances to the rest of your accounts.

It's a bit annoying that it takes two steps (and preparing two different files for import), but I don't see a way to combine them easily.